# Synchronous loading of images in JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

The problem I encountered is that i have a function that validates a form and **must** return array of errors. In that function I need to validate if the image(from url) is valid {width,height}. I'm using onLoad function for checking that but that's async.

```
check(url: string, requiredDimension: ?Object) {
    // $FlowFixMe
    return new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            let img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                if (!requiredDimension || (requiredDimension.width === img.width && requiredDimension.height === img.height)) {
                    resolve({valid: true, message: 'Field is valid!'});
                } else {
                    resolve({
                        valid: false,
                        message: `Image not valid! Required dimensions are ${requiredDimension.width}x${requiredDimension.height}!`
                    });
                }
            };
            img.src = url;
        } else {
            if (requiredDimension) {
                resolve({
                    valid: false,
                    message: `Image not valid! Required dimensions are ${requiredDimension.width}x${requiredDimension.height}!`
                });
            } else {
                resolve({
                    valid: false,
                    message: `Image not valid!`
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

function validate(formData, errors) {
   Object.keys(formData).forEach((item) => {
       let response = check(formData[item], requiredDimensions)
       if(!response.valid) {
           //add errors
       }
   });
return errors;
}
```

To summarize things up. I need a sync way to detect is the photo valid dimensions. Function check work just fine, but the response is needed in function validate.

Comment: Could you please more specifically identify your problem for us? You have just given us a desired function and some code and we aren't sure what to look at.

Comment: @iHowell Sure. I have edited my code

Answer (score 0):

From editing the code it looks like you have an extra curly bracket near the end that takes the errors out of scope. In the function `validate`, you try to add to (what I assume is) an error array called (errors), but you never return it because of the extra curly brackets.